# How to send entire account balance to another address on Base

Tags: web3js, transactions, ether, gas, gas-price

The below code is what I used to transfer entire account balance to other address on the ERC20 network and it works fine on it, but not on Base. Maybe it's because Base has different transaction fee calculations. Any way to fix this?

```
export async function sendTransaction(
  secretKey: string,
  amount: number,
  to?: string
) {
  try {
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(secretKey, provider);
    const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
    const gasLimit = (
      await provider.estimateGas({
        to: to,
        value: amount,
      })
    ).toNumber();
    const valueAfterGas = amount - gasLimit * Number(gasPrice);

    const tx = await wallet.sendTransaction({
      to: to,
      value: valueAfterGas,
      gasPrice: gasPrice,
      gasLimit: gasLimit,
    });

    return tx;
  } catch (error) {
    log(`No transaction for ${amount} to ${to}`);
    errorHandler(error);
  }
}
```

`Error: insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS ]`

Comment: Since **Base** is an **L2**, transaction fee calculations are done differently on **L2** compared to **L1**. This [article](https://blog.kroma.network/l2-scaling-landscape-fees-and-max-tps-fe6087d3f690) might be helpful. I've previously attempted to calculate it, but was unable to arrive at the correct value. Please share the answer if you succeed.